# Design Manager not updating aspx from my html

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I am attempting to create a new page layout using SharePoint 2013's Design Manager.

When I upload my new page layout html file into the master page gallery, and then refresh the "Edit Page Layouts" page in the Design Manager, the status of my page layout is "Conversion successful" but when i look at the aspx page, it has not been modified at all. Furthermore when I view the preview, it is the same as the ootb one. I have even deleted the contents of the aspx file (left the file, just left it empty) and it still says "conversion successful" and shows the preview, and leaves the aspx file empty.
And yes, I have checked that the "Associated File" checkbox is checked for my html file.

What is actually used to display the preview, the html or the aspx?

When is the html converted into aspx? when the html is modified or when the Edit Page Layouts page is refreshed? how can i trigger that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like a cached version of the aspx is used to generate the preview, but i don't know.

The html is converted into aspx upon being uploaded to the Master Page Gallery - there is an event receiver attached to the Master Page Gallery that parses the html pages.

My aspx page was not updating due to the problem posted here: [Quick Launch on a page layout in 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61195/quick-launch-on-a-page-layout-in-2013)

when i removed that code, it worked like it should again.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I needed to remove a few more elements, but the idea was likewise.