# Adding branded Quick Launch Menu to a 2013 Custom Layout Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing-page

I have build an html master page with bootstrap header and footer, referenced JS and CSS.   Not much in the way of snippets apart from a search box in my header. All good

Ok, now I have created some custom layout page based on the Welcome layout. I have apply this to an OOTB Team site. Looks good but now I need to add my web part zones or web controls. First thing is a to apply my css to a quick launch menu so  I can dynamically display any links to lists and libraries in the pages with this layout. So how is this done:

- Is there a snippet since the control code is all at the .aspx level
- Do I need to build a custom accordion or the like

I have seen this [Quick Launch on a page layout in 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61195/quick-launch-on-a-page-layout-in-2013)  which is close to what I want. I just wonder if there are other techniques out there

Answer (score 1):

You can use a full bootstrap theme for SP2013 and it will have all the resources for what you need.
You can get a theme from here.
http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/theme/TheBootstrapTheme

Once installed and applied to get and accordion in the Quick Launch you just need to edit the master page and add a css class to the the MenuV.

```
<div id="menuV" class="accordion">
```

You can check how it will look in this link

http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/theme/TheBootstrapTheme/page/Menus/customize